# Issue with expanding/collapsing UITableView rows in section

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have an issue with expanding and collapsing UiTableView rows and not sure how to troubleshoot or what may be the cause. When the section expands it causes a jerking motion and other rows seem to move up and down.

Here is the issue:
https://www.useloom.com/share/14c1cdd27e7844dcad31dad30d4aa1ce

When the row is toggled the following code is executed:

```
    section.showPrompts = !section.showPrompts;    
    [self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:section] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try batching the updates within

```
[self.tableview beginUpdates];
... your code ...
[self.tableview endUpdates];
```

so that all of the animations are synchronized.

Comment: That doesn't seem to do anything. Still same issue.

Comment: Can you provide a little more detail in how the above snippet is being called? Are you in a UITableViewDelegate callback? It seems like you're contending with other animation in flight, but it's hard to diagnose without knowing more about the callstack.